# Circular Progress Button WPF/C# Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to make a button in my WPF windows application that is primarily a circular button. I have found plenty of tutorials online using numerous different methods such as templates and styling so that part I can figure out.

The catch is that I want the custom control (which is what I think I want because from my understanding just styles alone wont let me modify core functions of the button and user controls are more groups of already done controls) because I want something that is part button and part progress bar. I want it to be a circular button with a gray strip around the perimeter of the button a few pixels thick that when I press and hold the button I can start a circular blue strip around that gray perimeter and when the blue reaches the top after one revolution some event may be triggered in the code.

I have been trying to find stuff online but it seems like there is a lot of disjointed and confusing tutorials on how to make custom WPF controls. Some are for expression blend which doesn't totally match the blend that installs with visual studio community 2015 so I am just thoroughly confused and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow

Comment: Oh sorry, I can edit it to make it more specific. I really was hoping for a link to how to make custom controls or else maybe someone to offer their input on how they might do this.

Comment: So when your outer ring reaches full 360 rotation while in the pressed state, you just want to fire off a command/method or something? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: Correct. I want the one rotation of the ring to take a set amount of time (say 3 seconds) and when the ring finishes one revolution (or when 3 seconds have elapsed) from pressing the button then I want a function to be called which can execute some task. It is kind of like a click hold off time so that people have a chance to cancel their action before an action takes effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *necessarily* need a custom control. You can have a UserControl with a circular button, and overlay a circular Path over the edge of the button. Set that Path object's visibility to false initially, and when you detect a left click down event on your button, make that circular path visible and start a rotate transform animation on it. You should be able to expand on this to stop the animation when you want to; your description doesn't fully describe what ways you want it to stop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This actually sounds like exactly what I was looking for! I'll look more into overlaying circular paths and see where I can get to! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! I don't know why I just didn't suggest an ellipse like user2536990 did. An ellipse with a gradient brush set in the right way and rotating should be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can easy customize regular button or toggle button:

1. Open project in VS
2. Right click on xaml in solution explorer you want to edit
3. Click on "Design in Blend"
4. Select Assets tab
5. Find "Button" in controls and drag it to page
6. Right click on the button on page
7. Edit template -> Edit a copy -> OK
8. Objects and timeline tab -> right click on border -> Change layout type -> Canvas
9. Remove backgroun from the canvas in properties tab
10. Drag elipsis from Assets->Shapes
11. Adjust elipsis size
12. Goto States tab -> Selected "Pressed"
13. Change color of the ellipsis in pressed state
14. ... to be continue.